# How is it possible in Git that files silently lost between 2 commits?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-log

Me and coworker encountered this scenario in Git, where files went missing between 2 commits, but we don't see any "delete mode 100644 path/to/file" kind of output. Based on my understanding of Git, I don't see how this is possible.

Here are simplified trace info. Let me know if any further output would help investigation and I will happily append.

We located 2 consecutive commits in one branch:

```
git log --oneline
```

That gives:

[image]

Note `1423249` and `341c603`. I will now check out to each of these commits to show that one example file (there are more) is present in the previous commit `341c603`, but missing in the next commit `1423249`.

## 341c603

```
➜ git checkout 341c603
Note: checking out '341c603'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 341c603 v0.1.230
```

```
➜ git log  --stat --summary --  app/components/BreadcrumbNav/index.js
commit f88f71e4bec82a004626d2e1326bb1a1544675b3
Author: panguoliang <panguoliang@dae.org>
Date:   Wed May 8 13:31:05 2019 +0800

    ADD fiat module

 app/components/BreadcrumbNav/index.js | 41 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 1 file changed, 41 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 app/components/BreadcrumbNav/index.js
```

```
➜ ls -l  app/components/BreadcrumbNav/index.js
-rw-r--r--  1 wang.boyang  staff  888 May 10 10:10 app/components/BreadcrumbNav/index.js
```

It's there in `341c603`. It was created in an older commit. Now moving to `1423249`

## 1423249

```
➜ git checkout 1423249
Previous HEAD position was 341c603 v0.1.230
HEAD is now at 1423249 fix websocket, subscribe to current symbol
```

```
➜ git log --stat --summary --  ./app/components/BreadcrumbNav/index.js
(empty output)
```

```
➜ ls -l  app/components/BreadcrumbNav/index.js
ls: app/components/BreadcrumbNav/index.js: No such file or directory
```

It's not there! So, what are the changes in `1423249`? Was the missing file `app/components/BreadcrumbNav/index.js` deleted in `1423249`?

```
➜ git show --stat 1423249

commit 1423249134941968692d2094c64369017838d393 (HEAD)
Author: Wang Boyang <boyang@dae.org>
Date:   Thu May 9 12:59:59 2019 +0800

    fix websocket, subscribe to current symbol

 .eslintrc.js                       |   2 ++
 .prettierrc                        |  14 ++++++---
 app/containers/BarBox/actions.js   |  24 ++++++--------
 app/containers/BarBox/constants.js |   8 ++---
 app/containers/BarBox/index.js     |  22 ++++++-------
 app/containers/BarBox/reducer.js   |  18 ++++-------
 app/containers/BarBox/saga.js      |  20 ++++++------
 app/containers/BarBox/selectors.js |   5 ++-
 app/containers/BarBox/styles.js    |   5 ++-
 app/containers/TradePage/index.js  | 116 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++----------------------------------------
 10 files changed, 102 insertions(+), 132 deletions(-)
```

There's absolutely no change related to the missing file, `app/components/BreadcrumbNav/index.js`. So, what's happening?

## Edit

Below is a simplified output from `git log --graph`:

```
*   commit 47750dc0059d503dcd73de767fe9a1914070b6b9
|\  Merge: d1a0f6e 2115249
| | Author: justinji <justin5562587@gmail.com>
| | Date:   Thu May 9 17:40:01 2019 +0800
| | 
| |     resolve conflicts
| |   
| *   commit 2d8835e30a9a27f9eec687de573e4a77e66ed69a
| |\  Merge: 324857a 341c603
| | | Author: Wang Boyang <boyang@dae.org>
| | | Date:   Thu May 9 13:06:22 2019 +0800
| | | 
| | |     Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/test' into test
| | | 
| | * commit 341c60334919930ee5f731cae3660c80aefb2ca1
| | | Author: panguoliang <panguoliang@dae.org>
| | | Date:   Thu May 9 12:03:01 2019 +0800
| | | 
| | |     v0.1.230
| | | 
| | |   
| | *   commit 66eaf470248a01b6d7861f1b319335255363195c
| | |\  Merge: 5ec1650 63e528b
| | | | Author: panguoliang <panguoliang@dae.org>
| | | | Date:   Thu May 9 12:00:48 2019 +0800
| | | | 
| | | |     lint
| | | | 
| | * | commit 9f8b93645851d98b1ab08264de8700a0e0dff47c
| | | | Author: panguoliang <panguoliang@dae.org>
| | | | Date:   Thu May 9 11:58:41 2019 +0800
| | | | 
| | | |     ADD Fiat deposit
| | | | 
| | | | 
| * | | commit 1423249134941968692d2094c64369017838d393
| | | | Author: Wang Boyang <boyang@dae.org>
| | | | Date:   Thu May 9 12:59:59 2019 +0800
| | | | 
| | | |     fix websocket, subscribe to current symbol
| | | |   
| * | |   commit 6d2c1073689140b75758d0e008af183340f1842b
| |\ \ \  Merge: f730698 63e528b
| | | |/  Author: Wang Boyang <boyang@dae.org>
| | |/|   Date:   Thu May 9 10:39:23 2019 +0800
| | | |   
| | | |       Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/test' into test
| | | |
```

Findings: in (and after) the merge commit `2d8835e30a9a27f9eec687de573e4a77e66ed69a`, the files are lost. cat-file output:

```
➜ git cat-file commit 2d8835e30a9a27f9eec687de573e4a77e66ed69a
tree a46f997a76ff403d1ec0567913722787d72bf9f6
parent 324857aa9a26852a2c5699650366ac7797a85ac2
parent 341c60334919930ee5f731cae3660c80aefb2ca1
author Wang Boyang <boyang@dae.org> 1557378382 +0800
committer Wang Boyang <boyang@dae.org> 1557378382 +0800

Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/test' into test
```

## Edit2

The tool [difflame](https://github.com/eantoranz/difflame) gives below output:

```
➜ ~/Projects/difflame.py 341c603 2d8835e30a9a27f9eec687de573e4a77e66ed69a -- app/components/BreadcrumbNav/index.js
Processing line 48/48
diff --git a/app/components/BreadcrumbNav/index.js b/app/components/BreadcrumbNav/index.js
deleted file mode 100644
index bf18d9d..0000000
--- a/app/components/BreadcrumbNav/index.js
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,41 +0,0 @@
    341c603: v0.1.230
-341c603 (panguoliang 2019-05-09 12:03:01  1  ) /**
-341c603 (panguoliang 2019-05-09 12:03:01  2  )  *
-341c603 (panguoliang 2019-05-09 12:03:01  3  )  * BreadcrumbNav
-341c603 (panguoliang 2019-05-09 12:03:01  4  )  *
-341c603 (panguoliang 2019-05-09 12:03:01  5  )  */
```

Is there any way to find out **why** the merge was done this way (i.e. deleting files), so that it can be avoided in the future?

Comment: Is it possible you're somehow applying a diff-filter that is excluding deletions?  The only way I can reproduce this behavior is `git show --diff-filter=d --stat <commit>`, which excludes deletions from the output.

Comment: @meagar I did another git log, with --graph, and it shows that the 2 commits were coming from different branches. Does that info help?

Comment: They were created on different branches, but now exist on the same branch? Or they are *still* on different branches?

Comment: @meagar They are now merged. Appended output from `git log --graph`

Comment: Ok, so, `14232491` is not the parent of `341c603`, you won't find a deletion represented there. You need to inspect the merge commit, `2d8835e3`. My guess is that conflicts were resolved in a weird way and the file was removed as part of that commit.

Comment: @meagar `2d8835e3` should be the source of problem. The merge cause the files to be lost (though it's not easily shown in any difftool). What might be the sequence of events leading to this though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All comments and answers are tremendously useful. I eventually found out why.

First of all, like @meagar mentioned, file deletion is simply represented by a file blob not in a commit snapshot. As it turned out, the files disappeared during a merge.

With any sane mergetool, when faced with 2 parents where one added a file and the other did not, it would hint and likely add the file, or show a conflict like `modified in XXXX but deleted in XXX`.

This one didn't. Because I mistake the following 2:

`git merge -s recursive -X ours`

`git merge -s ours`

The latter would simply ignore the other parents. So changes from there are gone. There onwards, all doesn't work as expected and file deletions are wrongfully persisted

Answer (score 3):

If the revisions are one after the other (can't see it.... they might be on two separate branches because you didn't specify --graph) then `git show --name-status 1423249` should show the files as deleted.

PS given that the revisions are actually on two separate branches, it means that a *possible* deletion could have happened on any of the ancestors of the two revisions... or that there was no real deletion involved. It depends on the history of the 2 branches (common  ancestor might have the two files missing, one of the branches still has them missing, they were added on the other branch.... in this scenario there's no deletion involved).

Comment: That's great insight. I did another git log, with --graph, and it shows that the 2 commits were coming from different branches. They are now all present on this current branch, and are next to each other with default `git log` sorting order. What to check next?

Comment: Aaahhhh.... what? Getting those two revisions on a single branch "magically" (while keeping IDs) is not possible on git. So, the revisions are on two separate branches.... and if that is the case, there _might_ have never been any deletion. For example, on their common ancestor files A and B didn't exist. On one of the branches the files are still missing, on the other they are _added_. If you diff the two revisions, the file might show as deleted.... or added, depending on the direction of the diff. In other words, the fact that they are on separate branches creates many more possibilities.

Comment: They are now in a single branch by a series of merges... And the output is appended. Seems one of the merge is the root cause, but is there any further investigation I can do to understand *what was done wrong* so that it can be avoided

Comment: And even if there was a deletion, because they are on separate branches, it could have happened on one of their ancestors, not necessarily on any of those 2 revisions you are dealing with. In case you want to track `where it happened` you might consider using a tool I created for such a task: https://github.com/eantoranz/difflame

Comment: It doesn't matter that you merged them... that's stuff happening in the future (from the point of view of the revisions). If the files went really missing, it has to be on one of the ancestors of the two revisions.... not necessarily on one of those two.

Comment: Another way to see where the files went missing would be by using `git bisect`. Files are there? `git bisect good`. Files are missing? `git bisect bad`. That should take you to the revision where the files were deleted.

Comment: I run difflame and indeed it gave descriptive output, noting the missing file. Appended to question. But as to why it was merged that way, is it un-traceable?

Comment: Run `git merge-base` providing the two revisions you are talking about. Then check if the file is there. That will drive the conversation forward. Let us know.

Comment: Just in case, when you run merge-base, it doesn't checkout. You will have to checkout to the revision that merge-base provided as output or check with other means like ls-tree. Whatever you feel comfortable that will let you see if the file is on that revision.

Comment: Found out the reason. See my post